# Как открыть определенную картинку по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, html

столкнулся с проблемой. Есть два отдельных объекта, к каждому из которых привязан определенный popup. Сейчас при нажатии на кнопку появляются оба popup'а.
Как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку объекта, появлялся определенный popup?
HTML трогать нельзя. Желательно, чтобы работало через data-атрибуты.

```js
const itemBtn = '.item__btn';
const popupImg = '.popup__img';
const popupCls = '.popup__btn-close';

$(itemBtn).on('click', function() {
  $(popupImg).closest('.popup').show();
});

$(popupCls).on('click', function() {
  $(popupImg).closest('.popup').hide();
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.item__text {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.item__btn {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item__btn:hover {
  background: #008400;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
  overflow: auto;
}

.popup__content {
  max-width: 1170px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 150px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 15px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.popup__btn-close {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%0A%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='32' height='32' viewBox='0 0 32 32'%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cstyle%3E .btn-close %7B fill: %23579bde; fill-rule: evenodd; %7D %3C/style%3E%3C/defs%3E%3Cpath id='Forma_1' data-name='Forma 1' class='btn-close' d='M16,1A15,15,0,1,0,31,16,14.957,14.957,0,0,0,16,1Zm2.182,15.273L23.3,21.386a0.659,0.659,0,0,1,0,.955l-0.954.954a0.737,0.737,0,0,1-.477.2,0.619,0.619,0,0,1-.477-0.2l-5.114-5.114a0.33,0.33,0,0,0-.477,0L10.682,23.3a0.736,0.736,0,0,1-.477.2,0.619,0.619,0,0,1-.477-0.2l-0.955-.954a0.659,0.659,0,0,1,0-.955l5.114-5.114a0.33,0.33,0,0,0,0-.477L8.773,10.682a0.659,0.659,0,0,1,0-.955l0.955-.954a0.659,0.659,0,0,1,.955,0L15.8,13.886a0.33,0.33,0,0,0,.477,0l5.114-5.114a0.736,0.736,0,0,1,.477-0.2,0.619,0.619,0,0,1,.477.2L23.3,9.727a0.659,0.659,0,0,1,0,.955L18.182,15.8A0.327,0.327,0,0,0,18.182,16.273Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
  background-size: contain;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  right: 5%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 32px;
}

.popup__btn-close:hover {
  filter: brightness(120%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='item'>
    <span class='item__text'>show first</span>
    <button data-id='#popup-1' type='button' class='item__btn'>
      popup
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>
    <span class='item__text'>show second</span>
    <button data-id='#popup-2' type='button' class='item__btn'>
      popup
    </button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='popup'>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <button type="button" class="popup__btn-close"></button>
    <img id='popup-1' class="popup__img" src='https://picsum.photos/300/200'>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='popup'>
  <div class="popup__content">
    <button type="button" class="popup__btn-close"></button>
    <img id='popop-2' class="popup__img" src='https://picsum.photos/200/300'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно так)

если чуть подумать, то можно дописать `ActionMapper`, проверки (закрывать на клик вне попапа, к примеру)

```js
class ModalManager {
  constructor() {
    this.actions = {
      'open': 'open',
      'close': 'close'
    };

    this.modal = null;

    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);

    document.addEventListener('click', this.onClick, false);
  }

  onClick(e) {
    const node = e.target.closest('[data-action]');

    if (!node) return;

    const name = node.getAttribute('data-name');
    const action = node.getAttribute('data-action');

    if (!action || !this.actions[action]) return;

    this[this.actions[action]](name);
  }

  open(name) {
    const modal = document.querySelector(`.modal[data-name='${name}']`);

    if (!modal)
      throw new Error(`A modal with name ${name} doesn't exist on the current page`);

    modal.classList.add('modal_open');

    this.modal = name;
  }

  close(name) {
    const modal = document.querySelector(`.modal[data-name='${name}']`);

    modal.classList.remove('modal_open');

    this.modal = null;
  }
}

new ModalManager();
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0);
  width: 400px; height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.modal_open { display: block; }
```

```html
<button data-action="open" data-name="first">Open first modal</button>
<button data-action="open" data-name="second">Open second modal</button>

<div class="modal" data-name="first">
  first modal

  <button data-action="close" data-name="first">Close first modal</button>
</div>

<div class="modal" data-name="second">
  second modal

  <button data-action="close" data-name="second">Close second modal</button>
</div>
```